# How to calculate Dynamic Moving Average without any date reference?

Tags: powerbi

I am looking for some clarification with regards to moving average calculation. My data looks like the screenshot attached.

[image: Sample Data]

I checked online for suggestion but it went awry. Most of the moving averages work with date (in date format). As I am having Day...only in numeric format...I am not sure which function would help me to get Mov_Avg for 3 Day time frame on the Increment col. My desired output should be col 3_day_Avg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your column **Increase** (created using Power Query) and create this below measure for your required output-

```
last_three_day_average = 

VAR current_row_day = MIN(your_source_table_name[day])
VAR current_row_country = MIN(your_source_table_name[country])
VAR current_row_case_death = MIN(your_source_table_name[cases/death])
VAR current_row_count = MIN(your_source_table_name[count])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_source_table_name[increase]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_source_table_name),
        your_source_table_name[country] = current_row_country
            && your_source_table_name[cases/death] = current_row_case_death
            && your_source_table_name[day] <= current_row_day
            && your_source_table_name[day] >= current_row_day - 2
    )
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Alternatively, if you wants not to use Power Query, You can use Custom column and that case you have to convert your Measure **increase_using_measure** as a column. As aggregation is required, you can not refer a measure for that. Here below is the code for column-

```
increase_using_column = 

VAR current_row_day = your_source_table_name[day]
VAR current_row_country = your_source_table_name[country]
VAR current_row_case_death = your_source_table_name[cases/death]
VAR current_row_count = your_source_table_name[count]

VAR previous_day_count = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    your_source_table_name[count],
    your_source_table_name[day],current_row_day-1,
    your_source_table_name[country],current_row_country,
    your_source_table_name[cases/death],current_row_case_death
)

RETURN if(previous_day_count = BLANK(),current_row_count, current_row_count - previous_day_count)
```

Now you can use the above column created using DAX in your Last 3 days average calculation as below-

```
last_three_day_average = 

VAR current_row_day = MIN(your_source_table_name[day])
VAR current_row_country = MIN(your_source_table_name[country])
VAR current_row_case_death = MIN(your_source_table_name[cases/death])
VAR current_row_count = MIN(your_source_table_name[count])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_source_table_name[increase_using_column]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_source_table_name),
        your_source_table_name[country] = current_row_country
            && your_source_table_name[cases/death] = current_row_case_death
            && your_source_table_name[day] <= current_row_day
            && your_source_table_name[day] >= current_row_day - 2
    )
)
```

Output will be same as shown above.